# tomcat 7 + jersey + hibernate 4.5.1 - NameNotFoundException - tried everything

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, jersey

Thanks in advance for any help.  I'm at my wit's end with this one.  I've got everything setup (I think properly) but nothing works.  So posting here in the hopes that someone can help.

POM.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>iam</groupId>
  <artifactId>iam</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>IAMS Web Service</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.5.1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <hibernate-core-version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate-core-version>
        <codi.version>1.0.5</codi.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate-core-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate-core-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--  jackson dependencies for pojo/json support -->
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- end jackson deps -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- junit test and jersey client features -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.9</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                <version>11.2.0.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!--  Weld/CDI Begin -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
                <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <finalName>iam</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <packagingExcludes>src/test/*</packagingExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <!-- copy-dependency plugin -->
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore />
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" 
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="iamwsDev" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
  <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/id1dev</non-jta-data-source>
  <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="****"/>
  </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>IAM Web Service Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <!-- Don't allow scanning of resources, set each resource individually (below with provider.classnames) -->
        <!-- 
            <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>******</param-value>
            </init-param>
         -->
        <!--  comma separate the list of resource providers -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
                <param-value>
                    ******.resources.*****
                </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>****.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>*****.ServiceContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>**** Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <resource-ref>
      <description>DB Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/id1dev</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Server.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 --><Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/id1dev" password="****" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@<url>:<port>:<sid>" username="*****"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

And FINALLY, running simple code like the following is throwing an exception (stack trace later):

```
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa");
    if (factory != null) {
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }
    return null;
}
```

STACK TRACE:

```
   Got Connection jdbc:oracle:thin:@iddb1.dev.id.ubc.ca:1521:id1dev, UserName=*****, Oracle JDBC driver, 
    Success obtaining connection
    2014-01-31 15:31:53 DEBUG logging:53 - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider
    2014-01-31 15:31:53 WARN  HibernatePersistence:58 - HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
    2014-01-31 15:31:53 WARN  HibernatePersistence:58 - HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
    2014-01-31 15:31:53 WARN  HibernatePersistence:58 - HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
    2014-01-31 15:31:53 DEBUG ClassLoaderServiceImpl:139 - Incoming config yielded no classloaders; adding standard SE ones
    2014-01-31 15:31:54 DEBUG HibernatePersistenceProvider:102 - Located and parsed 1 persistence units; checking each
    2014-01-31 15:31:54 DEBUG HibernatePersistenceProvider:110 - Checking persistence-unit [name=iamwsDev, explicit-provider=org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] against incoming persistence unit name [iamwsDev]
    2014-01-31 15:31:54 DEBUG ProviderChecker:106 - Persistence-unit [iamwsDev] requested PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider]
    2014-01-31 15:31:54 DEBUG LogHelper:117 - PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: iamwsDev
        persistence provider classname: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
        classloader: null
        excludeUnlistedClasses: false
        JTA datasource: null
        Non JTA datasource: java:comp/env/jdbc/id1dev
        Transaction type: RESOURCE_LOCAL
        PU root URL: file:/Users/nchecknita/UBC/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/iamws/WEB-INF/classes/
        Shared Cache Mode: null
        Validation Mode: null
        Jar files URLs []
        Managed classes names []
        Mapping files names []
        Properties [
            hibernate.default_schema: CWLOGIN
            hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
            hibernate.show_sql: false
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: none
            hibernate.format_sql: false]
    2014-01-31 15:31:54 DEBUG IntegratorServiceImpl:63 - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator].
    2014-01-31 15:31:54 DEBUG IntegratorServiceImpl:63 - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccIntegrator].
    2014-01-31 15:31:54 DEBUG IntegratorServiceImpl:63 - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cache.internal.CollectionCacheInvalidator].
    2014-01-31 15:31:54 DEBUG IntegratorServiceImpl:63 - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator].
    2014-01-31 15:31:54 DEBUG StrategySelectorImpl:79 - Registering named strategy selector [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [MySQL5] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect] (replacing [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect])
    2014-01-31 15:31:54 DEBUG StrategySelectorImpl:79 - Registering named strategy selector [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [MySQL5InnoDB] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] (replacing [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect])
    2014-01-31 15:31:54 INFO  Version:54 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
    2014-01-31 15:31:54 INFO  Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    2014-01-31 15:31:54 INFO  Environment:346 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    2014-01-31 15:31:55 DEBUG ServiceBinding:85 - Overriding existing service binding 
[STUFF SNIPPED]
    2014-01-31 15:31:56 INFO  Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
[MORE STUFF SNIPPED]
strategy [enhanced-table] -> [org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator]
    2014-01-31 15:31:56 DEBUG Configuration:1841 - Preparing to build session factory with filters : {}
    2014-01-31 15:31:56 DEBUG HibernatePersistenceProvider:80 - Unable to build entity manager factory
    org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/id1dev]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
        at ca.ubc.iamws.model.DbConnect.getEntityManager(DbConnect.java:24)
        at ca.ubc.iamws.resources.EmployeeAutoCreate.getIt(EmployeeAutoCreate.java:66)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:402)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:349)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:comp/env/jdbc/id1dev] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:comp].
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:114)
```

Comment: I did add some **** in to mask out private details...

Comment: Hi @Nena, did you solve your problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: Hi there artaxerxe, i just noticed our post now - no i never got it fixed.  I had posted some additional detail, but whomever moderates the posts deleted it, because they deemed it "not an answer".  I didn't go back in and update my original question, because without the original question, it wouldn't make sense to add the additional detail without completely rewriting the question in the first place.  As you can tell, it takes a considerable effort just to write and properly frame a question.  Sorry I couldn't be of further assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is not finding the datasource 'java:comp/env/jdbc/id1dev', check your datasource config.

Add a context.xml to your META-INF folder containing this,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/id1dev" global="jdbc/id1dev" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</Context>
```

it creates a reference inside the context of your app to the global datasource you declared in server.xml

Comment: either that or remove the 'hibernate.connection.datasource' property from your persistence.xml

Comment: By datasource config, do you mean the server.xml/context.xml?  I did include that file (server.xml), see above.  I doesn't appear to have anything wrong with it but could be something I'm missing?

Comment: Here's the relevant section from server.xml (i also tried just putting this in the context.xml, neither is working):  <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/id1dev" password="****" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@<url>:<port>:<sid>" username="*****"/>                                Also, here is the snippet from context.xml:        <ResourceLink global="jdbc/id1dev" name="jdbc/id1dev" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

Comment: sorry. first thing first, you're giving hibernate two different ways to access your database in persistence.xml, you should use either 'hibernate.connection.datasource' or 'javax.persistence...', but not both, go with one and remove the other.

Comment: if you picked the 'hibernate.connection.datasource' config then check the update to my answer, put that context.xml and tell me how it goes

Comment: what did you do and what did you get? please provide more detail

Comment: HI - thanks for your help.  I posted the new persistence.xml in the original question.  And I included the new stack trace which has more details about the exception being thrown.  I bumped up the log levels on hibernate to get more logging output.  I had to snip some stuff out though because the post can't exceed a certain length.

Comment: I'm wondering,is it possible that running in only a servlet container, I have to use plain old Hibernate Sessions instead of trying to get an "entityManager"?  Maybe I MUST have a EJB container to use entityManager?  The documentation for servlet spec 3 seems to indicate that I _can_ use a non-jta dataSource and use EntityManager, but it's not working the way my understanding is from what I've read.

Comment: nope, your problem still is that hibernate can't find your datasource, did you add the context.xml to META-INF like i said? if you didn't, do it, and then try changing 'java:comp/env/jdbc/id1dev' to 'jdbc/id1dev' in your persistence.xml

Comment: I tried that also, I'm getting the same error:  `Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/id1dev] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:114)`